# Linux UDP: where does the UDP datagram lose?

Tags: linux, network-programming, udp

I have a application running on sender and receiver, with **UDP** protocol. The UDP buffer size is about 70 or 1024 bytes so there is no UDP fragmentation happens.

From `ifconfig/sar` level, I did not see significant UDP loss.

But from application level, I see ~30% loss. I see the same with `iperf3`/`ntttcp-for-Linux`/`netperf`.

Where does the loss happen? Is this caused by UDP arrives IP stack out-of-order? How can I confirm this assumption?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that the receiver buffer is too small.

On the receiver side, `netstat` reports high "`UDP: packet receive errors`" in `netstat -s`.

Problem is solved by enlarging the receive buffer:

```
# sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=33554432
# sysctl -w net.core.rmem_default=33554432
```

Comment: Remember to restart the application after applying the above sysctl change.